# Optimize speed of Levenshtein distance of many words

Tags: performance, matlab, levenshtein-distance

I have a cell array dictionary which contains a lot of words (ca. 15000).

I want to compute the function `strdist` (to calculate the Levenshtein distance) for all the couples of words. I tried in two ways, but they are both really slow. What can be a more efficient solution?

Here is my code (dict_keys is my cell array of length m):

1)

```
matrix = sparse(m,m);
for i = 1:m-1;
    matrix(i,:) = cellfun( @(u) strdist(dict_keys{i},u), dict_keys );
end
```

2)

```
matrix = sparse(m,m);
for i = 1:m-1;
  for j = i+1:m
     matrix(i,j) = strdist(dict_keys{i},dict_keys{j});
  end   
end
```

Comment: Function-inline the source code and use an outer loop to iterate though all `r`'s (the first input to the function)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function 'strdist' is not an inbuilt matlab function, so I guess you took if from the [File Exchange](http://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/17585-calculation-of-distance-between-strings/content/strdist.m). That's also why both your approaches are roughly equal in time, `cellfun` internally just expands into a loop.

If `strdist` is symmetric, i.e. strdist(a,b)==strdist(b,a) you can however save half the computations. This seems to be the case, so only calculate all cases of `j<i` in the second loop (which you are doing).

Otherwise you could implement strdist in C as a mex function and probably see some significant speed improvements. A C implementation of the Levenshtein distance can be found for example at [rosettacode.org](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance#C).

Or dig into the details of how the algorithm computes the distance of two strings and see if you can vectorize it and reduce the runtime from quadratic so less. This however is probably not very easy.

Finally if you have the Parallel Computing Toolbox licensed and a multicore CPU you can easily parallelize your code since the `strdist` calls are completely independent of each other.

Comment: Yes, I took it from the File Exchange. It is symmetric, indeed in the second piece of code I only do half of computations. But it is still too slow.

Comment: I didn't totally solve, but I got great improvements through a new mex function and using Parallel Computing Toolbox!

Answer (score 1):

There are several much faster methods like Levenshtain Automata. See

1. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_automaton
2. http://blog.notdot.net/2010/07/Damn-Cool-Algorithms-Levenshtein-Automata
3. https://www.google.com.ng/search?q=Fast+approximate+search+in+large+dictionaries (many different papers. You can also go by (reverse) references from papers on CiteSeerX.