# How to compare elements in the same list efficiently and create an adjaney list

Tags: python, arrays, list, adjacency-list

I have an excel file that contains ~74000 entries, which are then stored into an array. I want to compare each element with each other (i.e compare [0] with [1], [2]. [3] .... then compare [1] with [0]. [2]. [3]...) and based on the string edit distance, create an adjacency list

```
for i in range(0,len(words)):
     word1 = words[i]
     f.write(word1)
     for j in range(0, len(words)):
          word2 = words[j]
          if Levenshtein.distance(word1,word2) == 1:
                f.write(f"{words[j]} ")
f.write("\n")
```

but my current approach takes n^2 time, and with the number of element it'll probably take quite a bit of time, wondering if there was a better approach / method to potentially save the computing time.

I know I could limit the comparisons by changing the inner for loop to

```
for j in range(i+1, len(words))
```

but I could like to keep everything, in-case i need to do a random sample on some inputs, and would need to verify all of their neighbors are present

Comment: well you can work in upper triangular matrix or lower triangular matrix only, can save duplicate comparision

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/27562134/18135454 for some thoughts on filtering for a given Levenshtein distance (1 in your case) more efficiently than calculating the full distance for every string pair.

Comment: Do you think it would be useful if I ran the array in parallel concurrently  with something like 

``with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
results = executor.map(function_name, array)
or result in results:
f.write(result)``